# Axis2 multiple connection authentication issue

Tags: web-services, tomcat, servlets, apache-axis

I have two servlets that access two corresponding Axis2 web services on the same host. One of the servlets is read-only, while the other writes to a database.

Each of the Axis2 web services uses BASIC authentication. The read-only web service uses a system account, while the write web service uses the user's credentials (which are submitted as part of a web form).

The problem I'm running into is that the servlet called *second* always fails authentication to its web service. For example, I can query the read-only service through it's servlet all I want, but I get a "401: Authorization Required" when I try to use the write service. If I call the write service first, I get the same error when I try to use the read-only service.

Here is how I am setting the credentials for the connections in the servlets:

```java
Stub service = new Stub(serviceUrl);
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setUsername(username);
auth.setPassword(password);
auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

service._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

The servlet that accesses the read-only service has this code in it's constructor. The servlet that accesses the write service has this code in it's doGet/doPost method.

It seems that the credentials for the first service called are getting cached somewhere, but I can't find where that could be. I saw a possible solution [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#setting_cached_httpclient_object), but I can't find where `WSClientConstants.CACHED_HTTP_STATE` is defined. [The comments in this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4288) seems to imply that it's part of `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants` but it's not there.

Specifics:

- Axis version: 1.5.1
- Tomcat Version: 6.0.26
- Java version: 1.6.0_23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the connections to the two different services were using the same JSESSIONID. Thus, the connection to the second web service was trying to use a session authenticated for the first web service, causing the error.

My solution for this was to define an `HttpClient` for each service, done by the following

```java
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager manager = new MuliThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(manager);

ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext();
context.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, client);
context.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, true);

Stub service = new Stub(context, serviceUrl);
```

This allows both servlets to have a separate session for their corresponding services.

Answer (score 0):

The important point is to create a dedicated ConfigurationContext.

I've solved in a simpler way using a default config context when creating the stub without the multithreaded connection factory

stub = new MyStub(ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext(), myServicesUrl);